# How can I make my own android SDK for ads?

Tags: android, sdk, admob

I know this question is insufficient. But I am totally confused to create a new android SDK for ads. How can I create my own SDK for ads like mAdserve,mopub,Admob etc. I want to track user install, clicks, etc also to my server.When a developer integrate this , he can easily access the ads with 2 or 3 line codes.I want to load my own ads page. How can I make such android SDK, please suggest some tutorials or sample codes, I am new to android . Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Go to MoPub and look at their SDK. AdMob just made their SDK open... This is no small task at all. Whether these will help depends more on your server and ad serving architecture. There are many, many layers of complexity but publicly available SDKs should help you to at least see how some companies have approached it. (e.g. what are your ad formats, sizes, interstitials, types, polling, filling rules, requests, location requirements, caching policies, serving verification, app identifiers, maturity rules, targeting requirements, etc.)

A similar question might be "how can I build an app like Twitter? It seems easy enough if I had a tutorial..."

Comment: if you are using a 3rd party SDK, then of course. But the SDK itself will dictate the behavior and you will have to write custom code to monitor events if the SDK doesn't provide appropriate listener calls. Also, you can swap out ad content, but the rules get complicated fast... you are better off using an ad platform with mediation like MoPub. You can extend their SDK to do custom events, etc.

Comment: I am looking to add my own server like mopub and,lokking to edit with mopub SDK, is it possible JIM?? or any other way to solve ?? Is there any other SDK easier than Mopub??

Comment: You can do in-house ads with MoPub with their server. If you want to use your own, I think it's possible. I looked at the MoPub SDK for similar reasons but decided it was too big a task considering their in-house ad serving options.